# Quadratic programming solver that guarantees a boundary point?

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming

I have a problem that I have expressed as the minimization of a convex quadratic program with linear constraints. The problem is that I want to disallow any point that is strictly interior (i.e. I only find the answer useful if it is on a vertex of the feasible region.

I'd like to do this without modifying the objective function. I have already considered several modifications that would make this a non-issue, but they all have the unfortunate result of making the program non-convex.

By my estimation my only option for an efficient solution would be a solver that uses a penalty method to approach a solution from the outside of the feasible region. Does anyone know a decent solver for this?

My current objective function is a sum of parabolic cylinders.

Comment: I found this... [link](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#Pkg:QPSolver) They say it is based on a generalization of the simplex method, which would seem to imply that it only returns vertices. It also seems to run pretty fast. Does anyone know anything about this package? Does it have polynomial time guarantees for example? Maybe I should just try it and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just find the vertices of the feasible region and then take the one which minimizes the objective function?  This should just involve a bit of linear algebra and then a limited number of evaluations of the objective function.

Comment: Except that the number of vertices can grow at an exponential rate. It would get out of hand rather quickly.